# Why can't I see Patents SE in the Stack Exchange homepage?

Tags: discussion, about-page, stackexchange

[image: Se]

Why is Ask Patents not present in the above [grid](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#)?

Comment: It's already there now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because patents.SE is still in **[Private Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63401/what-is-private-beta-status)**.

Sites will be listed there once they enter **Public Beta**.

<sup>(Sadly I'm having more trouble than expected finding canonical references for this though.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I don't even know that there is something like _private beta_ :D

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: I've asked on meta.SO for proper canonical definitions of these terms: **[Canonical definitions of the Stack Exchange jargon terms “private beta” and “public beta”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146112/canonical-definitions-of-the-stack-exchange-jargon-terms-private-beta-and-pub)**

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: Also please see the ["Area 51" FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) which tells you lots of information about beta sites on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Sure i'll have a look and sorry for the trouble :)

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: No trouble at all - questions like these are already making the site better by getting the glossary improved! (-:

Comment: And why only this beta site has a special theme?

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: I think the special theme is because it's not a normal beta site, there are various US organizations involved in it. But maybe see [this meta post about patents.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146103/what-is-patents-se-and-why-is-it-secret) too ...

Comment: I came to know about this site from that MSO post :)

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: The Ouroboros is complete (-:

Comment: Someone recently commented on your question in MSO differentiating private and public betas.. In that he said,private betas have a 'sketchy' theme. And he also mentioned that private beta is only for users who committed for that on Area51. But i didn't commit for this. Still i'm accessing it. So,is this really _that_ different?

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: It does seem to be quite a bit different as stated in the answer to the original meta question. But this comment thread is getting pretty long so maybe leave comments over there or join the chat room and see if anybody is there?

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

Looks like it's there now:

[image: SE Grid]